# Setting particular registry value in Windows 7 with WiX

Tags: windows-7, wix, registry, windows-installer

The following code works in Windows 7 x86, but not x64. What's the difference and how do I go about setting this key? It also works when I install it on Windows XP having changed the feature to install on Windows XP.

```
<Component Id="WallpaperPermW7" Guid="{c6427f8f-ce18-4675-9ea4-3292c18c897f}" Feature="W7Feature">
    <RegistryValue Id="WallpaperRegW7" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background" Name="OEMBackground" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes">
</Component>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks Yan, I can see the registry going into the [WoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows) folder now,

But, I want it to install it in the same path for both 64 and 32 bit systems if I add the Win64="yes" attribute then it won't install on 32 bit systems will it?

Is there a way around not having two packages?

Comment: No, it won't. Moreover, if you mark it with Win64="yes" the entire package won't install for 32bit (if I remember correctly). I'm not sure there's a workaround, but I would rather search for alternatives in changing requirements: is it really required to write that registry value?

Comment: Yes, to set the oembackground I need to change those settings, for now I have split them into 2 installers, and the 64bit version doesnt work for some other reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your package is 32-bit, and hence on 64-bit systems the path you specify in the "key" attribute of RegistryValue element is mapped to a different hive:

> Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft...

instead of

> Software\Microsoft...

That's why you don't see your value in place you expect it to be.

In order to correct this you'll have to mark your component as 64-bit (Win64='yes'), but this will mean that the entire package is 64-bit, and as a result you'll have to author a pair of packages, one for 32-bit, one for 64-bit... Probably, you can revise your requirements to avoid this.